# Issues regarding reloading a react-based webpage

Tags: node.js, reactjs, react-router

I'm a student working on a project to benefit other students, and I am currently facing a problem with reloading with any other url than the main path.

The webpage is written from scratch (more or less) in React with no backend, but I still hoped that it would work. I am using react-router to change sub-directories.

I have understood that there is a difference between server- and client-url's, and that this issue most likely is related to that. In the app's main directory "webpage.com" everything works fine untill the page is refreshed. If a sub-directory such as "webpage.com/link" is "called" directly, I recieve an error. You can go and try for yourself btw.

Does anyone know of a nice way to fix this? Do I need to implement something like Node.js to fix this? If so, how? I would prefer not to use a hot-fix such as redirecting all sub-directory calls (such as "/link" (an actual page) or "/kejrngo" (jibberish) ) to "/".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've cloned your project locally and it seems you have a problem with the server. As you said yourself it seems that only open url for your page is http://ifistudenter.no where at the beginning all application is rendered. After you try to refresh the page you are looking for a path that isn't available on the server and that is the reason you get 404.

What seems to be a problem is React Router itself with Apache server:

Please look at this: https://www.malikbrowne.com/blog/using-react-router-with-apache hope it helps